# I have upgraded to ionic 4 but my project doesnt support the version now I need to downgrade to ionic 3. What should i do?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4

I have accidentally upgraded to ionic 4 but I want to downgrade from ionic 4 to ionic 3.

Comment: `npm install -g ionic@3.9.2`

Comment: _How_ did you perform the upgrade?